# Testing Vue + vuetify and v-mask causing error

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

My Vue component uses a mask from [v-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask) and it works fine.

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="cpfCnpjField"
    v-mask="maskcpfCnpjField"
></v-text-field>
```

In my spec file spec I'm importing the VueMask

```
import VueMask from 'v-mask';
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueMask);
```

When I run my tests with jest, the component cannot be mounted.
The compiler throws

> console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1884
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at updateValue
> (C:\workspace\front-farm\node_modules\v-mask\dist\v-mask.js:401:35)

Any idea of what can be happening?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to shallowMount the component. That worked for me